# FuelUX tree: Default item/folder to selected on create

Tags: tree, fuelux

Does anyone know how to default a FuelUX tree item/folder to selected on create.

I know I can call tree.tree('selectItem', $('#' + node.id)) after the fact to select nodes, but it requires a lot more effort (especially with a large multi-leveled tree) compared to just setting it on creation.

Something like this, where an attribute called "Selected"  marks the item as selected

```
result.push({
    name: value.text,
    type: ((parentNode != null) && (!$.isEmptyObject(parentNode))) ? 'item' : 'folder',
    children: children,
    parent: parentNode,
    **selected: value.selected**
    dataAttributes: {
        id: value.id
    }});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could set [an attribute](http://getfuelux.com/javascript.html#tree-usage-datasource) in the item `attr` object and then create an event that when `loaded.fu.tree` is fired would find all those `data-default-selected="true"` and click them.

Make sure multi-select is on.

Answer (score 1):

If you have these codes bellow...

```
<ul id="tree1"></ul>

var myTree = $('#tree1');

myTree.on('loaded.fu.tree', function (e) {
    // need to add technique here
});
```

Then you could use `my-selected-item` class in your `children` >> `attr` like below...

```
'children': {
    'Cat': {text: 'Cat', type: 'item'},
    'Goat': {
        text: 'Goat', type: 'item',
        "attr": {
            "class": "my-selected-item"
        }
    },
    'Tiger': {text: 'Tiger', type: 'item'}
}
```

Now write technique line in the above...

```
myTree.on('loaded.fu.tree', function (e) {
    myTree.tree('selectItem', $('.my-selected-item'))
})
```

Hope this will make `selected` the `Goat` item.